# How to style deep inside shadow trees

Tags: polymer

I have a problem with styling deep shadow trees. How can i apply some styles into shadow-dom ?

Here is i tried:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/custom-style.html">
<custom-style>
  <style is="custom-style">
    vaadin-text-field [part='input-field']{
        display: none;
    }
  </style>
</custom-style>
```

But its not working. Any advice ?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're just trying to hide the `<vaadin-text-field>` inside the `<vaadin-date-picker>`. There's already an element ([`<vaadin-date-picker-light>`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-date-picker/html-api/elements/Vaadin.DatePickerLightElement)) that excludes the `<vaadin-text-field>`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you can't, see:

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom

"The HTML elements in your template become children in your custom element's shadow DOM. Shadow DOM provides a mechanism for encapsulation, meaning that elements inside the shadow DOM don't match selectors outside the shadow DOM."

Instead you need to extend the webcomponent, making custom version of it with your styles, the linked documentation gives information on that too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vaadin-themable-mixin to style parts elements.
But please note that once theme is loaded, it's will become global, so that all vaadin control in your website is styled by your theam.
read more at:
https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/wiki/1.-Style-Scopes